# Why is feeling and hearing are the same in Italian?

Tags: etymology, latin, psycholinguistics, italian, roots

*Sentire* means hearing, and at the same time feeling, in Italian and it's used passively in both senses.

- *Mi sento male* - I feel bad
- *Ho sentito il tuo nome* - I heard your name

Why among all senses have Italians  chosen hearing to represent feeling?

Comment: They didn’t; the meaning of _sentire_ broadened from meaning just ‘feel, sense’ in general terms to also referring to sensing with the ears specifically. It went feel -> hear, not hear -> feel.

Comment: Then the question would be why "hear" became synonymous with "feel" and this did not happen to the other senses?

Comment: Or perhaps rather why they started using ‘feel’ to mean ‘hear’ and not ‘see’ or ‘taste’ for example – it’s not like Italian doesn’t still have a verb meaning ‘hear’ (_udire_). The two are not really synonymous, they just have overlapping meanings. Unfortunately, questions like this (“why did change X occur in language Y?”) are rarely answerable. Whatever the reasons were, they are generally lost to time and can only be answered by the people who were there when the change happened – if even they knew at the time.

Comment: One could ask the analog question: why do English people use the same verb for "feeling with the touch" and "feeling with the soul"? Italian speakers do not... :)

Comment: Note that hearing is the sense associated with language. And that in English, hearing is the sense with three different lexical verbs representing sensation: _hear_ and _listen_ for the non-volitional and volitional verbs with agent/perceiver as subject, and _sound_ for the flip sense with percept as subject and perceiver implied. Vision has only _see_ and _look_ for perceivers, and also _look_ for flip. The other senses use only one verb each: _smell, taste,_ and the generalizable _feel_.

Comment: In Ukrainian, the common Slavic verb [_чути_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%87%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8) (čúty) ['t͡ʂute], apart from its original meaning "to sense, to feel", means not only "to hear", but also "to smell". This shift of meaning _feel_ > _hear_ is not characteristic of Italian only, it is common across languages.

Comment: In French, *sentir* means ‘feel’ and ‘smell’.  How about other Romance languages?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to put the question is, why do English speakers use so many words to convey Italian *sentire*? Italian unifies various kinds of sensation (physical and mental) in a way that English doesn't. In English, you consume food by "eating" is, and we don't use different words for eating soft foods vs. tougher foods like meat that require beating the food with your teeth. Some languages make such a distinction.

Ultimately, these connections between meanings and word are conventionalized by historical processes. Therefore you would want to look at the historical meanings of that root in Latin. What happened to Latin audiō → udire; what were the uses of *sentiō* in Latin and how about the Indo-European predecessor. Why did the meaning of **sent-* become so limited in Germanic?

Comment: is this an answer?

Comment: @Esther It's a friendly and interesting frame-challenge answer.

Comment: @Araucaria-him yes, but it ends with questions instead of explanations.